# C programming strtok

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strtok

I am having trouble with the strtok function. I keep getting a 'bus error.' I wrote a function to return all the words within a line. Could somebody please point out my error?

**NOTE**: I am used to higher level languages

```
void extract_words(char tokens[WORD_MAX][WORD_LEN], char* line, int* sizePtr)
{
  printf("in extract words");   //for debugging

  char* chPtr = NULL;
  chPtr = strtok(line, " ");

  int size = 1;                             //words has one element
  while(chPtr != NULL) 
  {  
     strcpy(tokens[size++], chPtr);
     chPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");               //continue to tokenize the string
  }
  *sizePtr = size;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably didn't provide a valid address for `sizePtr` when you called it.

Comment: This is how I used sizePtr: int size; int* sizePtr = &size;

Comment: Maybe you tried to pass a string literal as the line parameter?

Comment: I did pass a string literal to testString, how do I fix that?

Comment: You should start `size` at 0 since arrays start at 0 in C.  You'd normally simply write: `int size; char tokens[WORD_MAX][WORD_LEN]; char *line = ...; extract_words(tokens, line, &size);` Even more often, you'd have `extract_words()` return the number of words: `int size = extract_words(line, tokens);` (also reversing the order of the other two arguments).  You should check your loop to ensure that `i` does not exceed `WORD_MAX-1`.

Comment: @vaughn Cato, post an answer, I fixed it because i was passing a string literal...

Comment: Initialize a character array: `char string[] = "your string literal";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtok modifies the string you pass to it, so it can't be a string literal.  You should be able to do something like this:

```
void extract_words(char tokens[WORD_MAX][WORD_LEN], const char* line_arg, int* sizePtr)
{
  char line[(WORD_LEN+1)*WORD_MAX];
  char* chPtr = NULL;
  int size = 0;

  strcpy(line,line_arg);
  printf("in extract words");   //for debugging


  chPtr = strtok(line, " ");

  while(chPtr != NULL) 
  {  
     strcpy(tokens[size++], chPtr);
     chPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");               //continue to tokenize the string
  }
  *sizePtr = size;
}
```

Note that I also initialized size to zero, since array indices start at zero.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

Should you try to use a separator?

That case, I have source code.

```
int split(char *src, char *div, char **result,int *size)
{
    int i, j, slen, dlen, key=0, start=0;
    slen=strlen(src);
    dlen=strlen(div);
    for(i=0;i<slen;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<dlen;j++)
        {
            if(src[i]==div[j])
            {
                src[i]=0x00;
                result[key] = src+start;
                key++;
                start=i+1;
            }
        }
    }
    result[key]=src+start;
    *size=key+1;
    return 0;
}
```

using

split(chatData, " ", cmpData, &tok);

" "  : token
&tok : count split word
chatData : original data

by korean Dalsam.